# XSD choice of elements and simple types

Tags: xml, xsd

How to write XSD, where should be the choice between simple and complex types.

For example, all of this XMLs:

```
<a>
  <b/>
</a>
```

and

```
<a>
  <c/>
</a>
```

and

```
<a>
  100
</a>
```

(there are only integers allowed in last XML) should be valid.

PS: only one element allowed within <a> tag.

```
<a>
  <b/>
  <c/>
</a>
```

is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<xs:element name="a">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="c" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Hope that helps.

Edit: I have update the sample. However you cannot restrict the type in your third example to integer. What you want to do is not supported by XSD.

Answer (score -1):

Could something like this:

```
<xsd:element name="a">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:choice>
      <xsd:element name="b">
        <xsd:complexType/>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element name="c">
        <xsd:complexType/>
      </xsd:element>
      <xsd:element>
        <xsd:simpleType>
          <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer"/>
        </xsd:simpleType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

save the situation?

Comment: No. You've said here that `<a>` may contain either `<b>`, `<c>` or some other element of simple type integer. However, the element needs a name, so that schema fragment is invalid.